# Have Javascript insert a backspace within ContentEditable Div

Tags: javascript

An odd request, I know. I want Javascript to pretend the user just pressed the backspace.

That's all I really want, if you want more info:
My last topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940882/need-to-set-cursor-position-to-the-end-of-a-contenteditable-div-issue-with-selec), gives more explaination. In short: I press a key, javascript converts the key to the greek equivalent, then puts that key in instead. The problem is, when onKeyUp is activated, it starts a function which looks for combinable character pairs put together (for accents) and inserts that key.

Answer (score 0):

Backspace example:

```
if (document.getElementById("text").value.length > 0)
{
    document.getElementById("text").value=document.getElementById("text").value.substring(0,document.getElementById("text").value.length-1);
}
```

Comment: I need it to specifically emulate a keypress event.