# Emulate Tab with Enter key in iOS webview

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, uiwebview

I cannot understand why it is still such a pain in 2016 to do basic stuff like this. All I want is to that the Enter key act like the Tab key in a UIWebView in iOS.

I searched a couple of hours and found similar posts like this one ([here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537558/how-to-force-enter-key-to-act-as-tab-key-using-javascript)). I even found a plugin ([PlusAsTab](https://github.com/joelpurra/plusastab)) but none of these seems to work with the iOS webview setup. Does anyone have an idea how to do it ?

I put a sample code page here so you can tell me what I do wrong :http://jsbin.com/gapivod/6/edit?html,css,js,output