# Enter key on input field make the webpage redirect to prev step in Django wizard

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-formwizard

I have django wizard contains 4 steps:
the first step is account step where user enters the account information
the second step is personal information, at this step I have some problem:

1. when the user press enter on some input field ( like card num field) the webpage redirect the user to the previous step ( Account step ),
2. the account page returned with all fields filled except passwords ( they are return empty)

I will show snapshot of the webpage [the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrabm.png), and I will provide the code:

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                              class="multiStep-form style-one simplePresentCart-two">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                {{ wizard.management_form|crispy }}
                                                {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                                                    {{ wizard.form.management_form|crispy }}
                                                    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                                                        {% crispy form %}
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                {% else %}
                                                    {% crispy wizard.form %}
                                                {% endif %}
                                                <div class="multiStep-footer">
                                                    <div class="multiStep-footer-flex">
                                                        <div class="multiStep-footer-left">
                                                            {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
                                                                <button formnovalidate
                                                                        name="wizard_goto_step"
                                                                        type="submit"
                                                                        class="primry-btn-2 lg-btn"
                                                                        value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% translate "prev step" %}</button>

                                                            {% endif %}
                                                        </div>
                                                        {% if wizard.steps.current == wizard.steps.last %}
                                                            <div class="multiStep-footer-right">
                                                                <input type="submit" class="primry-btn-2 lg-btn"
                                                                       value="{% translate "Register" %}"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        {% else %}
                                                            <div class="multiStep-footer-right">
                                                                <input type="submit" class="primry-btn-2 lg-btn"
                                                                       value="{% translate "Next" %}"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        {% endif %}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

- I have tried remove type="submit" from the prev. button, but still the enter key on any field on step2 redirect to the 1st page.
- my form submission works successfully, I mean prev. and next button works perfectly, just I have this issue on input fields
- I have tried put code in jQuery that handle the enter key pressing and it worked, but it will affect all inputs, and I also have many input fields in this wizard, so I need to fix the source of the problem.

Comment: _"I have tried remove type="submit" from the prev. button, but still the enter key on any field on step2 redirect to the 1st page."_ - you are _not_ clicking the button, you are submitting the form by pressing enter inside a text field - so the button is irrelevant. You will need to add a submit handler for the form, and then cancel the submission.

Comment: but pressing enter in input field ( text field/Date field) should work like tab.. I mean enter should propagate to the next field in the form !! but in my case it redirect me to the prev page ( first step)

Comment: The form getting submitted, when enter is pressed inside a text input field, is the normal behavior. If you want a different behavior - then you need to explicitly implement that yourself. (Something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/10537558/1427878)

Comment: please could u read the edit on my post? 
also if enter make form submit as u saying then why it redirect to the prev step and not to next step !!!?

Comment: okay, I will try the code in the link, but what makes my mind blowing that pressing enter in the first step works like tab... and I have not done any customization ?