# Can I change the keyCode property of an event in chrome?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

We are assigning new key codes to an onKeyPress event in IE with this code:

```
window.event.keyCode=65
```

In IE, this changes the key received by other event handlers in the chain, but this code doesn't work in chrome. Is there any way to do this?

Example HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="hotelfloornew" id="hotelfloornew" 
       onkeypress="uPPer();" size="25" />
```

Corresponding JS:

```
function uPPer()
{
    switch (window.event.keyCode)
    {       
        case 97:window.event.keyCode=65;break;
        case 98:window.event.keyCode=66;break;  
        case 99:window.event.keyCode=67;break;  
        case 100:window.event.keyCode=68;break;
.
.
.

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change KeyCode in javascript in google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404807/change-keycode-in-javascript-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `keyCode` property of an event is a grotty hack that only works in old IE. It should be read-only and is in all sensible browsers. Don't do it.

If you need to change the effect of a keypress, prevent its default action and do your own replacement action manually. If you want to map typed characters to other characters, [you can use code I've published before on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605347/96100).

Answer (score 3):

IE assigns a global event value, but that's not normalized. In other browsers, use the value provided to your callback :

```
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   console.log(event.keyCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doKey(e) {
        evt = e || window.event; // compliant with ie6        
        alert(evt.keyCode+' Pressed');
    }
```

window.event.keyCode is mostly for IE... Here is an exemple code that will alert the keyCode pressed in all navigators.