# change KeyCode in javascript in google chrome

Tags: javascript

i am using javascript to change KeyCode for automatic convert keybourd into persian keyboard.
my code is shown in below

```
function submitenter(myfield, e) {
    var key;
    if(window.event)
        key = window.event.keyCode;
    else if(e)
        key = e.which;
    var str=' !"#$%،گ)(×+و-./0123456789:ك,=.؟@ِذ}يُيلآةـ،/’د×؛َءٍف‘{ًْإ~جژچ^_پشذزيثبلاهتنمئدخحضقسفعرصطغظ<|>ّ';
    if(key > 31 && key < 128) {
        window.event.keyCode=str.charCodeAt(key-32);
        return true;
    }
    if(key==13 || key==8 || key==0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

<input type=text name="Name" onkeypress="return submitenter(this, event);">
```

this code work in IE but in **Firefox and google chrome** not worked

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: in chrome have no error but Code not worked

Comment: it use for change value of field that use this function

Comment: but not used in this sample

Answer (score 2):

`keyCode` is **read only** according to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent) which also states that this property is deprecated and recommends using `event.key` instead.

You might find [Firing a Keyboard Event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript) and [KeyboardEvent in Chrome, keyCode is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942678/keyboardevent-in-chrome-keycode-is-0/12522752#12522752) useful in creating a custom event for Firefox and Chrome respectively.

The custom event workaround for Chrome in particular is required because creating normal `KeyboardEvent`s [is bugged](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735).