# selection and range objects Contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, textarea, contenteditable

I have got a similar requirement like the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940882/need-to-set-cursor-position-to-the-end-of-a-contenteditable-div-issue-with-sele) . I am working on some project related to Ethiopian language called Amharic.The project involves automatically translating Latin characters to their Ethiopian letters on keypress. In Amharic, each of the Latin characters like t, m, n, ... are mapped to at least 7 characters. For instance, the letter t can be mapped to 7 families of the Ethiopian ተ letter (ተ ቱ ቲ ታ ቴ ት ቶ). Here when you simply press t it will be mapped to ት, when you press the letter t followed by e, it will be mapped to ተ. When you press the letter t followed by i, it will be mapped to ቲ and so on. I have tried the answer by Tim Down and its partly working in my case. At least the text is getting inserted at the proper position with respect to the cursor. However, the solution provided works only when I press the first letter (for example t) but when I try to press t followed by the vowels (a,e,i,o,u) it first display the core mapped letter (with t) and then the letter mapped with t and a. This is working perfect with textarea but failed to work with contentEditable div. My project is similar to the one given [here](http://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/amharic.htm).

I have tried to modify the answer as follows but still cannot move the curso to the end.

```
function insertTextAtCursor(text, value, stepback) {
    var sel, range, textNode;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
            range.insertNode(textNode);
            // Move caret to the end of the newly inserted text node   
             range.setStart(textNode, textNode.length-stepback+value);
            range.setEnd(textNode, textNode.length);                
            //range.collapse(false);
            // range.setStart(textNode, textNode.length);
            //range.setEnd(textNode, textNode.length);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);     

        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML(text);
    }
}
```

Can you please help me on how to modify the solution provided by Tim to fit to the problem?