# Check if user typed certain text in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it so that if the user types `@sometext`, the text turns a certain colour where the word starts with `@` and ends where there's a space.

For example, let's say the user types the following (and I'm using bold to substitute for colour):

> **@username** this is some text.

I know I have to use the following, but I'm not sure how to continue:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function() {

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Wouldn't that get everything that's in the textarea?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the color in the textarea, or display the text somewhere else in color?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845813/multicolor-text-highlighting-in-a-textarea-or-text-input

Comment: You can't style individual words in a textarea

Comment: You want to use contentEditable divs for such styling.

Comment: @Chandranshu So something like this? `<textarea contenteditable="true"></textarea>`. How then would I do what I need it to do?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995570/replace-last-character-while-user-typing-in-contenteditable-div/19997193#19997193. The OP had  slightly different requirements where he wanted to transliterate the characters into a different language as the user typed. You can adapt it for your use case or open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To take the text in the textarea and display color coded in a different element, put a tag around each item in the text that you want to set color to, and style that tag.

Example:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
  $('div').html($(this).val().replace(/(@[^ ]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/HCt6E/2/

Comment: @user623952: Yes, you are correct, I forgot the global flag. Now it works.