# Inject spans into contenteditable div while typing

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I'm trying to inject `<span>` elements into the text a user is typing into a `contenteditable` `<div>`. Input events (`DOMCharacterDataModified`) periodically trigger requests to a service that identifies certain entities in the text, and I'd like to update it accordingly. For example,

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    The New York Times is an American newspaper based 
    in New York City with worldwide influence and 
    readership.
</div>
```

becomes

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    The <span class="name">New York Times</span> is an 
    American newspaper based in <span class="loc">New 
    York City</span> with worldwide influence and 
    readership.
</div>
```

Is there any way I can inject `<span>` elements without replacing the `<div>`'s content, thus preserving the user's text cursor position?

Comment: [DOMCharacterDataModified is depreacted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). take a look to [How to change contenteditable input character, on keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485516/how-to-change-contenteditable-input-character-on-keypress)

Comment: Are you suggesting `keydown`? I'm aware of the deprecation, but thought that `input` would be the [way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: yes, the link (way to go) is the right one

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know if it will preserve the text cursor position, but a straightforward [JavaScript replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) should work, regardless of if it’s inside something that’s `contenteditable`.

```
str.replace("New York Times", "<span>New York Times</span>")
```

Comment: That doesn't preserve text cursor position, unfortunately.

Comment: Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-textbox and possibly save the position first, then apply the span, then put the cursor back?

Comment: I've tried hard with saving and restoring cursor position, but I haven't been able to come up with a bullet-proof solution – particularly with async service requests.